# How can I read the contents of a .txt file and store it to a global variable using Javascript?

Tags: javascript, xmlhttprequest

I have:

```js
var datahere;
var url = "/example.txt"
```

example.txt has the text "Hello World"

How do I get datahere to equal this string outside of any request?

I'm happy to include PHP into the equations if necessary.

Comment: Your question is quite vague and unclear. Where is this file, on the local machine or on a server? What does `XMLHttpRequest` have to do with it? Why would you introduce PHP into the mix (is there a server involved)?

Comment: It's on a server.

I XMLHttpRequest is what I've been told to use so far, but could get it to work.

PHP because it's on a server.

Comment: Great -- use the "edit" link to add the necessary information to the question. Note that this is a really basic use of `XMLHttpRequest`. You really should read some of the thousands of examples on the web which show exactly how to do this (you don't need PHP). Just any basic `XMLHttpRequest` example will do it.

Answer (score 0):

Like @J.T. Crowder said, your question is not very specific about your scenario. You can also find plenty of websites explaining in great detail how `XMLHttpRequests` work. What you want can be achieved with a simple request like this:

```
var result, url = "/example.txt";

var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
xhr.open("GET",url,true);
xhr.onreadystatechange = function(e) {
    if(xhr.readyState == 4 && xhr.status == 200) {
        result = xhr.responseText;
        document.writeln(result);
    }
};
xhr.send();
```

This specific script will run under any webserver, but it won't run if you open it locally.

Here's one of those websites that explain everything https://xhr.spec.whatwg.org/